# Mail is not going to one account

Tags: php, email

I have using the following code

```
$header .= "Reply-To: Some One <someone@mydomain.com>\r\n"; 
$header .= "Return-Path: Some One <someone@mydomain.com>\r\n"; 
$header .= "From: Some One <mydomain@myhost.com>\r\n"; 
$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"; 

mail("linto@test.com", "subject", "This is my message.", $header);
```

But the mail is not going to one particular account, but it goes to other accounts.What extra code or header  do i need to add to this

Comment: Did you check the spam folder?

Comment: yea, i have checked the spam folder, biut no mails

Comment: If there are no bounce notices in your mail server's log, then the remote server could be silently discarding it, in which case you'd need to ask that server's admins to check their logs (pretty please with sugar on top).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with BoltClocks comment, but not sure if I'm correct here, but you can try something like this

`mail("linto@test.com,someone@mydomain.com", "subject", "This is my message.", $header)`;

Maybe it works, otherwise I suggest you try it out using PHPMailer?

Answer (score 0):

The target account's mail server can reject your mail with different reasons. You have to check your mail transfer agent logs. Or just check the mail queue (ex.: exim -bp). If the undelivered message is in queue, the target server is not accessible or rejected the message.

Check Return-Path e-mail (someone@mydomain.com) for error reports about undelivered messages.

If you will send messages from not MX-server of domain, you should read about SPF.

At the end try to send messages using SSH from your server:

```
$ mail -a "From:someone@mydomain.com" -s Test linto@test.com -- -fsomeone@mydomain.com
Test <Ctrl-D>
Cc:
```

If the message still not delivered, the problem is not in mail() or PHP.